# How to preserve children state when changing parents in react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to React and working on an app that changes navbar layout and some other details according to screen size, but renders the same responsive content inside. The `<MyContent />` itself can vary according to the route or tab the user is visiting.

```js
function App() {
  const isMobile = useSomeHookToDetectIfMobile();
  return (
    {isMobile
      ? <MobileWrapper><MyContent /></MobileWrapper>
      : <DesktopWrapper><MyContent /></DesktopWrapper>
    }
  );
}
```

The thing is, if the user resizes the window, when changing layout all the state inside `<MyContent />` is lost and reset. What would be the most React way to maintain it on resize? Keep in mind that the shape of the state of `<MyContent />` can vary according to what components it is displaying, so I don't think lifting state up is the way to go. Also its state only concerns itself, so I don't think it belongs farther up the component chain. I think I am missing some key point about the problem or coming at it the wrong way. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I think instead of writing two different wrappers you should have a single wrapper and use media query on css, thats the better approach i feel here. And coming to the problem i think when you detect the change you switch to another component so whatever the user has been doing will go basically mounting and unmounting happens so it will have the default values i think in that case you need to lift up the state

Answer (score 0):

In this case, a simple local variable to keep the rendered content before the condition would be enough. That way, React can keep track of it and then it's always the same instance.

```
function App() {
  const isMobile = useSomeHookToDetectIfMobile();

  const content = <MyContent />;

  return (
    {isMobile
      ? <MobileWrapper>{content}</MobileWrapper>
      : <DesktopWrapper>{content}</DesktopWrapper>
    }
  );
}
```