# Conditional rendering of parent component in React

Tags: reactjs

I need to return either Porover or Card depending on the condition with the same children content. This can be done by taking the children content into a separate component and returning it like this:

```
true ? <Popover><ChildrenContent props={props}/></Popover> 
: <Card><ChildrenContent props = {props}/></Card>
```

But it seems to me that this is not the best solution in this case

```
<Popover dataCy="complexValidation">
      <Section marginBottom={3}>
      </Section>

      <Flex flexDirection="column" gap={3}>
        {validations.map((validation) => (
          <Flex.Item key={validation.text}>
            <Flex alignItems="center">
              <Icon name="check_circle" size="large" color={validation.isSuccess ? 'positive' : 'negative'} />

              <Flex.Item>
                <Typography variant="bodyText2" component="span">
                  {validation.text}
                </Typography>
              </Flex.Item>
            </Flex>
          </Flex.Item>
        ))}
      </Flex>
    </Popover>
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: He wants to wrap a child component with either `<Popover>` or `<Card>` depending on a condition and is wondering how to do it. He wants to find a more concise way to do it than copying his long code twice

Comment: Here, this might help you: https://blog.hackages.io/conditionally-wrap-an-element-in-react-a8b9a47fab2

Comment: Here's [an example of how the children can be rendered as a single instance](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61875892/1218980) and the parent applied after.